# Could not resolve view with name 'xmlView'

Tags: java, spring, configuration

On a development, acceptance, and production machine we have the same version of a Spring based web application running. Only on the acceptance machine the application supports both the XML view (/foo/bar.xml) and JSON view (/foo/bar.json).

Calling the XML view on the two other machines results in displaying the infamous "Could not resolve view with name 'xmlView'" error message. The JSON view works fine.

Since this web application is identical on all three machines (I double checked by using diff) it seems to me that this different behaviour is caused by some external factor.

Does anyone know if this is possible or should I still focus on the setup of the Spring configuration?